# Don't have Time Machine back up a file again if a Tag is added to it

Tags: finder, hard-drive, time-machine, finder-tag, macos

If I have a large file, let's say a 1 GB ISO file, and I add a tag to it through the Finder, so that there's a blue circle next to the filename now, then Time Machine will consider that the file has changed and back it up a second time.

So this one file takes up 2 GB of space on Time Machine now. Is there some way to prevent Time Machine from backing up the entire file if just a tag was added to it?

Comment: Have you seen evidence that Time Machine actually makes a second copy of a file if only its metadata has changed? I would expect it to just save a delta of the metadata.

Comment: Yes I recall this happening. I noticed that it didn't backup the entire file a second time if I put the file inside a folder, and just changed the tags on the folder.